# Wordpress blog hitting several CPU process on hostgator server than the limit, causing 500 server error

Tags: wordpress, cpu-usage, shared-hosting

I am using WordPress blog on my website [CodeMink.com](http://codemink.com). The Web host is hostgator's shared server. The control Panel provided by hostgator showing more then one index file processes. These processes become 10 to 20 sometimes and increase the CPU usage 8% to 12%. website goes down in this situation when total process exceeds 6 in number.. get frequent 500 internal server error. Plugins: XML sitemaps, W3TC, Wordpress SEO,

I am also using the plugins of wordpress WP 3 TOTAL CACHE with al caching enabled. normally 15 to 20 visitor visits my website at the same time. and total 4000 page views per day

Wordpress with latest version and The server has latest apache version. Processes list is showing something like...

PID_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**_CPU  Memory  
669 /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/site/wp-cron.php   0%   0.1%
28714   /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/site/wp-admin/admin.php    0%  0.2%
28066   /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/index.php  0%  0.1%
31856   /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/index.php  0%  0.1%
8534    /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/site/wp-admin/admin.php    0%  0.2%
6018    /usr/local/cpanel/cpanel ./frontend/x3/hg/processes.php 0.3%    0.1%    
16516   /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/index.php  0%  0.1%    
9675    /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/site/wp-admin/admin.php    0%  0.2%
29797   /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/index.php  0%  0.1%
5777    /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/index.php  0.5%    0.1%    
5041    /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/index.php  0.2%    0.1%
2373    /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/index.php  0.1%    0.1%
3681    /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/index.php  0.1%    0.1%
4730    /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/index.php  0.1%    0.1%
4379    /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/index.php  0.1%    0.1%
4293    /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/index.php  0.1%    0.1%
3212    /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/site/index.php 0.1%    0.1%
1030    /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/index.php  0.1%    0.1%
5850    /usr/bin/php /home2/codemink/public_html/index.php  0.5%    0.1%

Please help to recover from this situation. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely related to the underpowered or over-provisioned HostGator shared servers.  Since their purchase by EIG last year, they've migrated customers to new hardware, and from my experience (I host 40+ WP blogs with them) this new hardware or provisioning rules has created poor performance for any site that relies on MySQL such as WordPress.

Shared hosting is always a gamble as you rely on the hosting provider to manage the number of accounts, and the performance as a whole.  I've hosted with HG for years and they've been great, but since late 2013 the performance has been atrocious.

Caching is only a band-aid, as the core problem is MySQL performance and the over-crowding of the server.

Find another (non EIG) shared web host, or upgrade to a VPS to give you more control/protection from other customers.

Also, it's worth noting that Google XML Sitemaps plugin is a well known resource hog, and is explicitly not allowed by high performance WP hosts like WPEngine: http://wpengine.com/support/disallowed-plugins/

Comment: thanks. I changed my server to higher version and everything seems fine.